# Is it possible to set breakpoints automatically (e.g. by regular expression) in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I would like to set breakpoints only at some kind of wrong behaviour hints
(e.g. ERROR-trace macros, etc.) for being able to find possible errors early during development. So, I wonder if it is possible to set BPs at places in code found by regex? 
May-be using some scripting or automation features of VS.

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: Did you consider refactoring the code or modifying the macros so that it passes through one central dispatch function, in which you can then set a single breakpoint?

Comment: A unit test is worth 1000 breakpoints ... well, maybe not *that* many, but it sure pays off over time.

Comment: @Jon: Ok, in my current case it could be an option - I'm in control of the entire code. But mostly you have to deal with legacy code, "read only" code (code provided for reviews), etc. VS has very good BP-abilities, so I thought, it would be a good option.

Comment: @pst: well, what is actually a unit test? Why should it always be a piece of C++ (or same language as tested code)? Why can't you consider 1000 BPs set/reset automatically, depending of solution-target chosen, as 1000 unit tests :-) ? Finally BPs can trigger scripts, which in turn could generate test-report. Just an idea ;-)

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz A [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) tests *individual units* of source code. The native/target language is normally used out of simplicity -- but this is not strictly a requirement. Using a framework that utilizes (automatic) breakpoints sounds more like [integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). In general, however, I consider breakpoints a debugging tool and not a testing tool although it would be interesting to see a testing framework that said otherwise :) (A key point of a good testing framework is that it is automated.)

Answer (score 0):

You can place a breakpoint on all overloaded versions of a method in Visual Studio using this trick : write the name of the method in the search box (main toolbar) and hit F9.

If you want more power, you can use WinDbg. The command bm (Set Symbol Breakpoint) allows pattern-matching expressions like this (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details):

```
0:000> bm myprogram!mem* 
   4: 0040d070 MyProgram!memcpy
   5: 0040c560 MyProgram!memmove
   6: 00408960 MyProgram!memset
```