# Breaking as the code execution enters the Dll or Lib space

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I'm debugging a Dll used by OS mechanisms using microsoft visual studio(In my case it is a minidriver).

I want the execution to break as it enters the dll code I want it because I don't know when base smart card CSP calls which function.

Is there any means to do it instead of having breakpoints in all exported functions?

If not, do you feel this feature is necessary?

Comment: I think this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641379/is-it-possible-to-set-breakpoints-automatically-e-g-by-regular-expression-in

Comment: I think doesn't help that much, thanks for the attention though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure what you want to achieve - you need the program to break without setting breakpoints, or you need just an information into which function/method from the dll program will enter first? I think you can accomplish that with timeline profiling using for example dotTrace: https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/whatsnew/

Comment: I need realtime information about which function from my dll is being called and i'd rather the execution to break as the function is being called. Well maybe this is too much. is it?

Comment: And do this without infering dll itself?

Comment: One way or another... look into the link I've provided, I'm not sure whether you can do it in a real-time but it might be worth to give it a shot

Comment: I, don't get what you mean by "inferring the dll" :( but I think you're saying I should first study my dll and find out which function is being called myself. (maybe some tools like the one you linked can help me in that) Then I have to put the breakpoints manually while debugging.

Comment: timeline profiling is rather to get the information about the sequence of invoking functions/methods so it fits best your needs, although I'm not sure if you can do it online when you're running your application or is it possible only afterwards

Comment: I agree this will be the best way if there is no such tool. thanks for your time